# wrong <div> <img src="<?php construction?

Tags: php, html

I'm echoing some images using `<div> <img src="<?php...` construction.

The images are shown, but after each image there are always some strings left from my code.

part of my code is here:

1. getting image by:

   ```
    $image01= wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta($id, 'image_case_01', true),'full');
   ```
2. and echoing image in `<div>`

   ```
    <div class="images-container">
        <div>           
            <img src="<?php echo $image01; ?>" >        
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
3. Result - the image is echoed properly but after the image I have that string left from my code

   ```
    > " >
   ```
4. If i use

   ```
    <div class="images-container">
        <div>           
            <img src="/.../.../xxx.jpg" />          
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

then all is ok.

What is wrong with my code in 2.  ?

Comment: If I run your version 2. it works just fine, so there is something else getting in the way that you are not seeing and not showing us

Comment: Maybe if you look at the contents of `$image01` with a `var_dump($image01);` you may see something

Comment: Hi i check it with var_dump. The result is  - string(1087) "IMAGE ITSELF" ... i mean "string(1087)" and THEIMAGE enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: if i just do "echo $image01;" in a snippet - thenit works as expected - shows the image without anything else.

Comment: I suggested a `var_dump()` because you get more information about the variable when you use that.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this ?

```
<div class="images-container">
    <div>  <?php echo '<img src="'.$image01.'"/>'; ?>       </div>
 </div>
```

you probably have quote probleme , i'm surprised the image actually showed up as your php code is inside a '"'

EDIT: some mistake

EDIT2: my bad

so i did this and it worked

```
<html lang="en">
<?php $image01="erreur.png";?>
<head>
    <body>  
        <div>  
            <?php echo "<img src=".$image01."></img>"; ?>       
       </div>
   </head>
</body>
```

Comment: That has not actually changed the resulting output one jot

Comment: so my bad, look like we had to be more carefull if we quote inside the variable. Hope it gonna work with you :)

Comment: if I assign image file to the variable (like You did). Then It works and the out put is clear. The issue is that I need to dynamically get the image from a post metafield.

Comment: The `<img>` is self-closing tag. It is a bit strange to add a closing tag after it 

Comment: @IvanG well it doesn't change a lot just put $_POST['yourimage'] either inside the variable $image01 or directly in the html like src=".$_POST['yourimage']."> or i'am missing something?

Comment: with or without </img> i have the same output

Comment: @IvanDidyk yeah you could probably remove it

Comment: Thank You Xiko I will try that after few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me.
Instead of using 
 wp_get_attachment_image
 i used
 wp_get_attachment_image_src

  Now everything works as expected.
I still don't understand why i had such quotes aoround my images, which probably lead to my problems.
May be it is because I'm getting images from a metabox meatfield.
Thank You for your support.

Comment: Because the version that doesn't end in src returns the entire img tag, while the src version just the part that goes into the src attribute. It says so in the docs anyway.